# How to use Index and match funtion in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, indexing, match

I would like to use the following function in VBA.

```
=INDEX(Zones!$G$3:$S$273;MATCH($A2;Zones!$C$3:$C$272;);MATCH($B2;Zones!$G$2:$S$2;))
```

I use two tables. In the table "Data" in column C2:C I would like to transfer the searched results.
Can anyone help with VBA coding?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without having tested it myself now, shooting from the hip, the VBA replacement should be trivial:

```
public function zone(DBase as Range, Locale as String, Locales as Range, Service as String, Services as Range) as Variant
  Dim iLocale as Long
  iLocale = WorksheetFunction.Match(Locale,Locales,0)
  Dim iService as Long
  iService = WorksheetFunction.Match(Service,Services,0)
  zone = DBase(iLocale,iService)
end function
```

Needs error checking, of course.  I find your motivation still rather suspect  ;)  Personally, I would not do it.  Your ambition to import the data from elsewhere will most probably also not work as you intend.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot make out from your formula what you are attempting but sounds from your description like you are tying to create a Pivot Table which today you can readily create with Spill Ranges.  That is, no call for VBA me thinks.

Comment: No, In the table data, column A are the locations to which the goods have to be shipped. In column B is the delivery service. Based on these two arguments, I am looking in the table Zones  for the zone number. based on the zone number, the price for delivery should be determined later. The price table is not implemented yet.

Comment: What is wrong with FILTER?  =FILTER(Zones,(Locations=A)*(Shippers=B))

Comment: Since your Zone happens to be a number, you write, you can also consider SUMIFS

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean with filter. The above function works fine, but I would like to use this function in VBA. The workbook I am currantly creating will contains more sheets with different services for shipping and prices. This is the reason why I try to solve it via VBA.

Comment: Since you do not post a grid outline of your challenge, I can only second-guess what you are up to.  From what I am guessing, a spilling FILTER will do nicely.  Read the manual page for examples.  It seems most unlikely that VBA will be required to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Calling one FILTER (per sheet) or one VBA function amounts to the same.  The difference is that FILTER is a well-known built-in function and your VBA is not.  Anyone who comes new to your spreadsheet will have an easier time understanding native Excel than your UDF.  My $0.02.

Comment: Since you write that the function works as intended and it seems that you have some matrix of Zones indexed by Location/Service, my feeling is that your data transfer might happen when you write =INDEX(Zones!$G$3:$S$273;MATCH($A2:A;Zones!$C$3:$C$272;);MATCH($B2:B;Zones!$G$2:$S$2;))  That formula spills all your results.